# PHP e-mail sending class design

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, email

I'm working on a class, what will be able to send e-mails for our customers.  I need to help with review of my classes design. I'm trying to do it to be easy extendable in future. I'm thinking about using dependency injection to inject `InputReaderInterface`. But is it worth doing it?

- `InputReaderInterface` - has method: `getContent()`
- `WebReader` - for reading source e-mail HTML (implements `InputReaderInterface`)
- `ParamSetter` - for setting different `params` for users (implements `InputReaderInterface`)
- `$smtp` - class for saving access attributes for SMTP
- `Mailer` - uses PHPMailer class for sending e-mails

In the future, `params` will be loaded from the database.

```
<?php
$reader1 = new WebReader($mailUrl);
$message = $reader1->getContent();

$params = array(
  "test@test.com" => array(
    "customer" => "Name Surname"
  )
);

$reader2 = new ParamSetter($message, $params);

$mailer = new Mailer($smtp, $from, $alias);

foreach($rows as $row) {
  $reader2->setParamsFor($row["email"]);
  $message = $reader2->getContent();

  $mailer->sendMail($row["email"], $subject, $message);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Naming

Your names are... I miss the word to describe your naming overall... Either way let's start.

Some of your names are good. `$smtp, $from, $alias, $mailer` and so on. Some of your names need improvement. `$reader1` for example..
That reader would be better off as `$mailReader` or `$messageReader` or even `$webReader`.

Whenever you number your variables something is wrong..

Then there's your `$reader2`.. And this is what's breaking my understanding..

You called the Class it has `ParamSetter`, but you make it implement a `InputReaderInterface`, and call the variable `$reader`...

Make up your mind. Is that thing a setter, a reader or something entirely different?
It definitely looks like it's something different. ParameterSetter seems to reflect it's usage. Having it implement `InputReaderInterface` is definitely the wrong choice.

## Concept

Actually your whole concept of OOP seems to be incorrect. I'd expect `$message` to be a `Message` and not a "String". That would allow you to restructure your code to something like this, which looks waay more OOP to me:

```
<?php
    $messageReader = new WebReader($mailUrl);
    $message = new Message(messageReader->getContent());

    $params /* how you get your params at all... */
    $paramReader = new ParamReader($params);
    $mailer = new Mailer($smtp, $from, $alias);

    foreach($rows as $row) {
       $message->applyParameters($paramReader->getParameters($row['email']));
       $mailer->sendMail($row['email'], $subject, $message->getContent());
    }
?>
```

Of course this means you'd have to change some underlying mechanics. Also I just dropped your `InputReaderInterface`. In that setup it's not really helpful, as you use your classes differently.

Your `ParamSetter` was a `ParamReader` and some `Message`-functionality. Keep concerns separate, the `ParamSetter` does not need to know how a message works, and what parameters it wants. He shouldn't even tamper with the message. That would be a violation of the ["Principle of Least Knowledge",](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which is a very important principle for OOP designing.

Instead the only one altering the `$message` should be the `$message` itself. Thus your `ParamSetter` in fact just wants to be a `Reader`, who is used by the `Message`.